# redirecting stderr of powershell and obtaining exit status

Tags: powershell, redirect

I'm trying to check whether Docker is running using `Powershell`

I have written the following powershell snippet:

```
docker info
echo $?
```

This code snippet returns False if Docker Engine is not running and True if it is. So far so good. Now I want to suppress all output of docker info. I have tried to do this in various ways, like:

```
(docker info) 2>&1>$null
echo $?
```

This suppresses all output, but also changes the output of my exit variable.

What's the correct way to do this?

I'm using Powershell version 5.1.22621.2506 on Windows 11.

Comment: What version of PowerShell are you using?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- The simplest way to **suppress output from *all* output streams** in PowerShell is to use the following [redirection](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Redirection) (this also works with PowerShell-native commands).

  - **`*>$null`**
- To **query the (process) exit code** of the most recently executed external program (child process), use [automatic **`$LASTEXITCODE`** variable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Automatic_Variables#lastexitcode):

  - A process exit code is a system-level mechanism and is a number of type `[int]` ([`System.Int32`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.Int32)). By - widely observed - *convention*, `0` indicates success and *any nonzero numeric value* failure, with the specific nonzero number potentially indicating a specific failure reason.
  - By contrast, PowerShell's [automatic **`$?`** variable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Automatic_Variables#section-1) is a *Boolean* value, i.e. an *abstract* success-vs.-failure indicator, and also applies if the most recently executed statement was a *PowerShell* command.

    - In [*PowerShell (Core) 7+*](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/blob/master/README.md), the value of `$?` *reliably* maps onto the `$LASTEXITCODE` value: `$?` is `$true` if `$LASTEXITCODE` is `0`, and `$false` otherwise.
    - In *Windows PowerShell*, due to a bug, `$?` can report *false negatives*, namely whenever an external program (a) emits *stderr* output (which by itself does *not* necessarily indicate failure) *and* (b) a `2>` redirection is being used.<sup>[1]</sup>
      In other words: **When calling external programs, do not rely on `$?` in *Windows PowerShell***.

Therefore, the **cross-edition solution** is:

```bash
# *>$null suppresses all output.
docker info *>$null  

# Infer success from the exit code; in PS 7+ you may also use $?
# -> $true, if the Docker engine is running, $false otherwise
$LASTEXITCODE -eq 0
```

---

###### Optional reading:  PowerShell 7+ options for *acting* on external programs' exit codes:

*Windows PowerShell* lacks integration of external-program calls with its *error-handling* system (except *accidentally* and with *undesired results* in the `2>` case).<sup>[1]</sup>
In essence, you must use `if ($LASTEXTICODE -ne 0) { ... }` after every external-program call in order to detect and act on failure.

*PowerShell 7+* now offers the following features:

- `&&` and `||`, the [pipeline-chain operators](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Pipeline_Chain_Operators), which work analogously to their `cmd.exe` and POSIX counterparts (e.g in `bash`):

  - The RHS of `&&` / `||` is invoked only if the LHS indicates success / failure, respectively (as it would be reflected in `$?`, meaning that it also works for PowerShell-native commands)
  - The caveat is that only *commands and expression*, not whole *statements* can act as the RHS, so that `exit` and `throw` statements must be wrapped in `$(...)`, unfortunately; also, `$LASTEXITCODE` must be specified *explicitly* in order to relay an external program's exit code; e.g.:

    ```bash
    # Exit the script if docker indicates failure, and
    # pass the nonzero exit code through.
    docker info || $(exit $LASTEXITCODE)
    ```
- The [`$PSNativeCommandUseErrorActionPreference` preference variable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Preference_Variables#psnativecommanduseerroractionpreference):

  - If this variable is set to `$true` (`$false` is the default), PowerShell itself emits a *non-terminating error* in response to any external (native) program call reporting a nonzero exit code (in addition to any stderr output the program may have printed to indicate an error condition); the message template is: `Program "<name>" ended with non-zero exit code: <exit-code>`
  - If the [`$ErrorActionPreference` preference variable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Preference_Variables#erroractionpreference) is set to `'Stop'`, this non-terminating error then causes execution to *abort*; e.g.:

    ```bash
     $PSNativeCommandUseErrorActionPreference = $true
     $ErrorActionPreference = 'Stop'

     # If the Docker engine isn't running, the following error
     # occurs and execution is aborted:
     #  "[...] Program "docker" ended with non-zero exit code: 1."
     docker info
    ```
  - However, as of PowerShell 7.4 this implementation has *problematic aspects*:

    - Exit codes reported by `.ps1` scripts (which run in-process inside a PowerShell session, but can still call `exit` and set exit code) are unexpectedly *not* covered by this mechanism - see [GitHub issue #19062](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/19062)
    - The fact that a *non-terminating* error is emitted means that you can *not* perform ad-hoc error handling via `try / catch` - see [GitHub issue #18368](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/18368).
    - Similarly, there is no ad-hoc *override* if you want to deliberately ignore an anticipated failure - see [GitHub issue #20067](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/20067).

---

<sup>[1] For instance, `cmd /c 'echo stderr >&2 & exit 0' 2>$null; $?` mistakenly reports `$false` in Windows PowerShell, despite `$LASTEXITCODE` being `0`.</sup>

Answer (score 1):

#### Solution #1:

If using PowerShell 5.1, try this:

```
$(
   docker info
   $Results = $?
) 2>&1>$null
echo $Results
```

#### Solution #2:

Switch to PowerShell 7.4.1 or above.

From my experimenting, it appears that PowerShell 5.1 behaves differently from PowerShell 7.4.1 (And probably different from version 6 and up).

#### Testing method:

I do not have docker, but I found the following code produced the same results as described when Docker Engine is running:

```
CMD /C "ECHO;Test & EXIT 0"
echo $?
```

And this produced the same results as when Docker Engine isn't running.

```
CMD /C "ECHO;Test & EXIT 1"
echo $?
```

In PowerShell 5.1, this code had the same problem as described, but was fine in PowerShell 7.4.1 (Replace *<ExitCode>* with either `0` for Docker found, or a non-zero value if it isn't found.):

```
(CMD /C "ECHO;Test & EXIT <ExitCode>") 2>&1>$null
echo $?
```

But this worked as expected in both PowerShell 5.1 and 7.4.1 (Replace *<ExitCode>* with `0` or non-zero as mentioned above.):

```
$(
   CMD /C "ECHO;Test & EXIT <ExitCode>"
   $Results = $?
) 2>&1>$null
echo $Results
```